# Pattern run-length encoding

Tags: java, run-length-encoding

I'm trying to find the cleanest way to perform a run-length encoding based on patterns. The goal is to compress a string by factorizing a substring composed of several same patterns.

Original String:

```
start{3}{3}{3}{3}end
```

As you can see, there are 4 "`{3}`" patterns. It's possible to compress this String by expressing the run of 4 "`{3}`" patterns as `$4{3}`.

Compressed String I would like to obtain:

```
start$4{3}end
```

I tried the `String.replaceAll(regex, replacement)` method. I know that `myString.replaceAll("\\{([^<])\\}", "$1")` can replace a whole pattern by its value only but **I can't find how to detect and count a same-pattern run** length using regular expressions.

Is using regular expression a good idea or are there any other 'better' way to do this?

Comment: can't you use Pattern and Matcher and get group count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just get the output as follows. There should be more efficient approach than this. But hopefully this will help you

```
    String s = "start{3}{3}{3}{3}end";
    String pString = "\\{3\\}";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pString);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);

    int count = 0;
    while (m.find()) {
        count++;
    }
    System.out.println(s.replaceAll(pString, "-").replaceFirst("-{"+count+"}", "\\$"+count+pString));
```

Comment: This should be a good starting base to work on, thank you for helping!

Answer (score 2):

You could use `java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream` and `java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream` in conjunction with `ByteArrayInputStream` and `ByteArrayOutputStream` to gzip/gunzip your strings, which is probably better than writing your own compression algorithm (unless you can use knowledge about the data to be compressed).